# bad argument #2 to 'setmetatable' (nil or table expected)?

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk

I currently stuck on this with a corona app I'm creating.

I have a file structure like below:
App -> Classes -> Objects -> Ships

In the App folder is the main.lua, menu.lua, level.lua and Class.lua. In the Classes folder there is  Object.lua. In Objects, ship.lua and finally in the Ships are my different ships i.e. player and enemy.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.omidahourai.com/from-zero-to-oo-ardentkids-guide-to-object-oriented-lua-with-corona-sdk) and my code is almost completely identical to his (bar player and enemys classes), but still am receiving this error in the Class.lua is

*"bad argument #2 to 'setetatable'(nil or table expected)"*

The code I receive the error on is

```js
function Class(Super)
  Super = Super or Base
  local prototype = setmetatable({}, Super) -- receive error here
  prototype.class = prototype
  prototype.super = Super
  prototype.__index = prototype
  return prototype
end

Base = Class()

function Base:new(...)
  local instance = setmetatable({}, self)
  instance:initialize(...)
  return instance
end

function Base:initialize() end

function Base:get()
  local Instances = self.Instances
  if (not Instances[1]) then local obj = self:new() end
  return table.remove(Instances, 1)
end

function Base:dispose()
  table.insert(self.Instances, self)
end
```

I've tried changing the classes and changing the "setmetatable({},Super)" to "setmetatable(Super, self), putting all the classes in one file, I've read the lua docs, requiring the Class.lua in the mai, menu and the level.lua etc. and nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Class(Super)
  Super = Super or Base
  local prototype = setmetatable({}, Super) -- receive error here
  prototype.class = prototype
  prototype.super = Super
  prototype.__index = prototype
  return prototype
end

Base = Class()
```

Follow the execution of the code above.

You declare a function `Class` and then call it (and assign its returned value to `Base`).

Step through the execution of `Class` from the `Base = Class()` line.

```
function Class(Super)
```

The function takes one argument named `Super`

```
Super = Super or Base
```

You are allowing the `Super` argument to be nil/unpassed by using a default value of `Base`.
This call `Base = Class()` is not passing a value so this line `Super = Super or Base` has `Super` as `nil` and so evaluates to `Super = nil or Base` however the global `Base` is **also** nil as it has not yet been assigned to so you get `Super = nil`.

```
local prototype = setmetatable({}, Super)
```

This line then attempts to use `Super` (assigned from the line before) only it is, as we just saw, `nil` hence your error.

The bit from the tutorial that you missed (or at least missed in your posted snippet) is the **crucially important** `local Base` line **above** the `Class` function definition.

Comment: Can you clarify why the error `(nil or table expected)` when the argument `Super` is `nil`. Shouldn't Lua remove any assigned metatable and return the table when `setmetatable` is called with a `nil` metatable?

Comment: Hm... true, `nil` should be fine there. I wonder what you have `Base` assigned to instead. Try printing it out? `print(type(Super), Super)` just above that `setmetatable` line?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Possible that `Base` is a global (which is not a table) somewhere in the code that OP didn't post.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @Adam I added in the line `local Base` at the top of the class and still the same error. 
@Etan I printed the what you suggested and the result was  `nil nil` , `table  table: 05F884A8` and then  `Boolean true` as the a few classes inherit from this class.

Comment: So the first call isn't the problem, the third call is. What call gave you `Boolean true` as output?

Comment: I'm not sure I tried debugging and it seems to happen all in the one step, I call `local player = PlayerShip:new()` ,in the PlayerShip class the inheritance is done as follows `local Super = require("Classes.Objects.Ship")
local PlayerShip = Class(Super)` and the same for the ship class `local Super = require("Classes.Object") local Ship = Class(Super)`, from debugging I found that the `nil nil` is when the class is first required and boolean value seem to come after the ship class does `local Ship = Class(Super)`

Comment: Sounds like your `Classes.Object` module isn't returning the class and isn't assigning to the appropriate global so require is falling back to using `true`.

Comment: ok that makes sense. How would I fix that? or would i need to redo or change the class?

Comment: You need to return the class object from the module.

Comment: I'm glad you got this figured out but I think this question should probably be deleted. As written my answer is wrong and as written the question doesn't contain enough information to diagnose the problem. Instead of deleting you could add the information about the print debugging and the lines that triggered it to the question and I can update my answer to match if you wanted.